# Is there a way to access and view/modify APN settings on IOS 9.0.2

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way to access and view/modify APN settings on IOS 9.0.2

Previously, I had iOS 8.4 installed on my iPhone and I was able to access and modify the APN settings by going to:

> Settings > General > Cellular > Cellular Data

I currently have no way to modify or even view the APN settings after upgrading to 9.0.2 and the cellular data menu is gone, but I did switch to AT&T recently as well so I'm not sure if the APN settings were removed in 9.0.2, if using an AT&T SIM hides the cellular data/APN menu, or if that menu/option is hidden somewhere else altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news... good news.

Bad news... cellular APN settings are disabled on by carrier and/or iOS 9.

Good news... you can create the appropriate APN settings profile via your mobile browser of choice at unlockit.co.nz

Just select your country/carrier and tap Create APN, follow the prompts and that's it.